Scaling the image while moving the QSplitter so that it fits into the new available width
I load different images at runtime into a QPixmap / QLabel. The pictures have different sizes.
Following example does not work as expected:
self.systemPicture.setScaledContents(False)
self.systemPicture.setMaximumWidth(600)
self.systemPicture.setMaximumHeight(300)
self.systemPicture.resize(400, 300)
self.pixmap = QPixmap('Bilder/minion.png')
self.pixmap = self.pixmap.scaled(self.systemPicture.size(), PyQt6.QtCore.Qt.AspectRatioMode.KeepAspectRatio)
self.systemPicture.setPixmap(pixmap)

When moving the QSplitter the picture should scale into the new wide of the available space.

How can I get images to be scaled according to the available space?

As already stated in my comment to your previous question, QLabel doesn't provide aspect ratio capabilities when resizing. Either you install an event filter an set a different pixmap based on the available size (without setting a fixed or minimum size for the label) or you create a QWidget subclass that paints the scaled pixmap.
